# Cómo puedo mostrar una imagen protegida por .htaccess

Tags: php, html

Tengo una imagen que no se puede ver porque htaccess contiene "deny from all", para que no se puede ver si el usuario ingresa la dirección manuelmente.  Quisiera que se mostrara solo por medio de la etiqueta img. Cómo se puede hacer eso con un script PHP.

Comment: Hola Jorge, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio y lee [ask]. Esta pregunta podría mejorarse añadiendo la búsqueda e intentos que hayas realizado así como las dificultades que te hayas encontrado. Dale a [edit] y añade esa información adicional.

Comment: una pregunta un tanto curiosa, por qué la tienes protegida por .htaccess? Te lo pregunto porque quizás exista otro método para eso que no requiera de .htaccess y que pueda resolver tu problema.

Comment: Hola @Jorge. Cuando se especifica `Deny from all`, directamente no se puede acceder al recurso. Probablemente te sirva usar algo como lo que se explica en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/134289/127. Por favor comentá si resuelve tu problema.